# I want to get data from other website using link

Tags: php

I have the link example http://www.9apps.com/android-games/Flopfrog/
what I want is to get if somebody searches flopfrog it should search from the database where I have all links and find the details like .  I am trying from last 1 week.  Here is my code. I am able to get  tag what I want is to have more than 10k links if sombody search flopfrog it should find that word from an txt file where all the links are there than do this step

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.9apps.com/android-games/Flopfrog/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step1 = explode( '<h1 class="name">' , $content );

$second_step1 = explode("</h1>" , $first_step1[1] );

echo "the name of the app is ". $second_step1[0]." this is the test";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $second_step1[0];
```

Comment: why using txt file when you can use a database ?

Comment: Attempt to clean up the English. Intent was unclear is some places, so I hope I didn't "clarify" incorrectly...

Comment: i have all links in txt thats why mrid